# Переключение радиокнопок по очереди на javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребята, нужна помощь. Есть несколько инпутов с типом "радиокнопка". Можно ли сделать так, чтобы инпуты переключались с помощью кнопок (div) "вперед" и "назад"? Т.е. сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на "вперед", атрибут checked передавался следующему инпуту, а при нажатии на кнопку "назад", атрибут checked передавался предыдующему инпуту. Проще говоря - переключать радиокнопки с помощью div.btn-next и div.btn-prev.
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: да, так сделать можно!

Comment: Можете подсказать как?

Comment: нужно использовать javascript: находишь текущую активную радиокнопку, и в зависимости от нажатой кнопки - ищешь предыдущую или следующую радиокнопку и делаешь ее активной.

Comment: мне бы код(( сам я его не напишу, я пока новичок

Comment: тогда стоит обратиться к справочнику по языку. например [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: пример - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/mfjungoj/4/

Comment: soledar10, спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#prev').on('click', function() { switchRadio(-1, getCheckedRadio()) });
$('#next').on('click', function() { switchRadio( 1, getCheckedRadio()) });

function switchRadio(direction, index) {
  var inputArr = $('input').toArray();
  inputArr[index].checked = false;
  var targetIndex = index + direction;
  if (targetIndex < 0) {
     targetIndex = inputArr.length - 1;
  } else if (targetIndex > inputArr.length - 1) {
     targetIndex = 0;
  };  
  inputArr[targetIndex].checked = true;
};

function getCheckedRadio() {
  var radioIndex;
  $('input').each(function( index ) {
    if (this.checked) {radioIndex = index};
  });
  return radioIndex;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="radio" disabled>radioA</div>
<div><input type="radio" disabled checked>radioB</div>
<div><input type="radio" disabled>radioC</div>
<div><input type="radio" disabled>radioD</div>
<button id='prev'>prev</button>
<button id='next'>next</button>
```

[Рабочий пример на фиддле](https://jsfiddle.net/y43rfod9/2).

Comment: Синхронизируйте код в сниппете и на фиддле, ибо они разные и тут нерабочий код.

Comment: исправил, спасибо.